# Can I use link.h on a cygwin install?

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I have installed the latest version of Cygwin, selecting the following packages during setup:

- libgcc1
- gcc
- gcc-core

And created a file (test.c) with only this line:

```
#include <link.h>
```

Then ran the following from my Cygwin bash:

```
$ gcc test.c
```

... but got this error:

```
test.c:1:18: link.h: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: On Debian, it's as easy as just installing the `libc6-dev` package, but Cygwin... That's a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is based on the Win32 subsystem, which means it uses Windows' executable format (COFF) and dynamic linker, i.e. it does not have an ELF dynamic linker. Hence providing the ELF-specific `<link.h>` would probably make little sense.